# Imported object is locked to world origin

Tags: import, .fbx

I try to import an fbx file which I have done many times before. Now suddenly it is locked to world origin so I can't move it. It is getting deformed when I try to move it because it is locked there.

The object is an animation figure from Mixamo. I am using Blender 2.81. I have even tried to restore factory settings, it won't help either.

[image: Pivot point is locked as you see here]

Answer (score 0):

A few things you could do to fix this:

1) set the origin of the fbx file you imported to it's own geometry.

You can do this by going to *object > transform > origin to geometry* in object mode with the object selected.

2) you can set the object to be it's own user.

This is a fix for an error caused by linking objects from other scenes. Somehow your object might have a similar response, so setting it to have it's own user may help.

You can do that by going to *object > make single user > object*. Or if it has a material or data then *object > make single user > object & data & materials & tex*.